# Using "for loop" in SAS SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

I am using SQL in SAS. I have lots of similar variable names in my data, such as "var1, var2, ..., var100". I know it could be written like

```
proc sql; select xx from xxx where var1 = a or var2 =a or var3 =a;run;
```

I wonder if SQL has a function like "for loop" to make this task easier?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As Tom indicated, this would be significantly easier in a data step:

```
data want;
   set xxx;
where whichc('a', of var1-var1000);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database variant, you might be able do this:

```
... WHERE a IN (var1, var2, var3, etc);
```

but that will be the best you can do, and I don't know if SAS supports it.

Comment: No, SAS does not.

Comment: @Joe - if you check the _SAS 9.4 SQL Procedure User's Guide,_ you'll find that SAS does support the SQL `IN()` condition.

Comment: It doesn’t work with variables in the IN operator though (at least it didn’t when I tested it).

Answer (score 0):

There's a `Do` loop functionality in every interation of SAS as far as I know.

IIRC, I think it works something like :

```
%do i=1 %to [##];
     ... do iterative stuff ...
%end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use macros to do the work.
For example:

```
%macro loopQuery;

  proc sql; 
    select xx 
    from xxx 
    where var1 = a 
     %do i=2 %to 100;
       or var&i.=a
     %end;
    ;
  run; 
%mend;

%loopQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WHICH()` or `WHICHC()` function to make that type of test.  It will return the index of the first variable that matches and zero if none match. SAS will treat 0 as false.

```
where which(a,var1,var2,var3)
```

Unfortunately if you use PROC SQL you must list each variable name. Unlike DATA step it does not support variable lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can macrovariable and then use it. But it is long tedious process and datastep is much simpler. You can do this in proc sql as shown below.

```
/*first create dataset to test*/
data have;
  input var1 var2 var3 var4 newvar  a;
  datalines;
 10 20 30 40 60 10
10 20 30 40 60 90
10 20 30 40 60 20
;
run;

 /* create macro variable*/
 proc sql;
   select catt(name, "  =  ", " a  or ") into :VAR SEPARATED by " "  
 from  dictionary.columns 
 where memname = 'HAVE'
 and prxmatch("m/^VAR\d+$/i", trim(name)) > 0;/* to find variable var with  digit*/

%put &VAR;
```

It gives var1  = a  or var2  = a  or var3  = a  or var4  = a  or

```
/* do a substring to remove last or */
%let final_var = %substr(&var, 1, %length(&var)-2);

%put &final_var;
```

It gives var1  = a  or var2  = a  or var3  = a  or var4  = a

```
 /*Now you can use the macro variable in your query, will give you desired 
result*/

proc sql;
select * from have
where &final_var;
```